# How to get XML representation of a fluent mapping - is it possible?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

As the title says, is it possible to get hands on the XML representation of a fluent nhibernate mapping? And if it is, can this be used directly with Hibernate for Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [section in the Fluent NHibernate wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/show/FluentConfiguration) covering the export of the xml mapping. Section at the bottom headed 'Exporting hbm.xml mappings'

Have not tried it but don't see any reason why the mapping file shouldn't work in Hibernate with minimal modification

Comment: Thanks, I will try it out. Guess you meant "shouldn't work" :)

Comment: Oops, certainly did. Corrected